# "Life finishes" vs "life is finished"

Tags: semantics, passive-voice

To convey that someone arrives at the end of his life or simply dies, which sentence is more correct or more common? I prefer the first.

> His life finishes.
>
> His life is finished.

If the second one is legitimate, can I assume *he* is responsible for the action *finish* (i.e., interpret the sentence as *he finishes his life*)? If so, what about the following sentence?

> I'm done grading the exam papers.

Who is responsible for the action *do*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *his life finishes*, *[finish](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/finish_1)* is used as an intransitive verb. In *his life is finished*, *[finished](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/finished)* is used as an adjective. Both are correct. Neither means he is the performer of the action.

In *I am done*, *[done](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/done_2)* is used as an adjective.

Comment: If the argument finished and done are both adjectives holds, it solves my problem.

Answer (score 7):

You've expressed a wish to use the word "finished", but it's not the word a native speaker would use.

More common phrases are:

> His life is over.
>
> His life has ended.

If you want to convey that the person is responsible for the action of ending their life, you could use:

> He has ended his life.

Be careful - that means suicide.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use "end" E.g:

> His life ended